# Is it possible to create a button using dat.gui

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I would like to create a button using dat.gui library. In a perfect world, this would work like this:

```
gui.add("button", "click me");
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This creates a button with text left aligned.

```
var obj = { add:function(){ console.log("clicked") }};

gui.add(obj,'add');
```

Comment: Have you found this documented anywhere?

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple words to the button label?

Comment: @nils yes, `gui.add(obj, 'add').name('Custom Label');`

Answer (score 32):

FWIW, dat.gui assumes the GUI type based on the target's initial value type.

- boolean => checkbox
- int/float => slider
- string => text input
- function => button

Examples can be found here:
http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage

Answer (score 0):

The chrome experiments example link above is no longer live, but there's a great fiddle; forked and added the button example from [Loneydatum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18380889/3133263).

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanB/qpwsnuxd/3/

```
var object4 = { add:function(){ alert("clicked") }};
gui.add(object4,'add');
// original fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ikatyang/182ztwao/
```