# Load a file using a dat.GUI button?

Tags: javascript, html, input-type-file, dat.gui

I already know how to create buttons using dat.GUI (passing in functions as described in this question: [Is it possible to create a button using dat.gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366229/is-it-possible-to-create-a-button-using-dat-gui)). I want to make a button that triggers a load file event like you would do with `<input type="file" id="file" name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" />`
Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Based on [Programmatically trigger "select file" dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595389/programmatically-trigger-select-file-dialog-box))

You call the hidden input button from the dat.GUI button's function.

```
<input id="myInput" type="file" style="visibility:hidden" />

<script>
var params = {
    loadFile : function() { 
            document.getElementById('myInput').click();
    }
};
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(params, 'loadFile').name('Load CSV file');
</script>
```

Comment: I realize this is a bit old, but this absolutely does not require jquery.
Replace `$('#myInput').click();` with `document.getElementById("myInput").click()` and it'll work just the same.

Comment: You can't programmatically trigger a click event for a file input for security reasons.